# Why does my dv1394src to ogg file pipeline stall?

Tags: gstreamer

I am attempting to demux a live recording from a MiniDV camera using the dv1394src element and then transcode it into a vorbis/theora ogg file. My pipeline below stalls after a few seconds. I think I have queue elements in the right space.

```
gst-launch -e dv1394src ! dvdemux name=demux \
  oggmux name=mux ! queue ! filesink location=/tmp/test.ogg \
  demux. ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! queue ! mux. \
  demux. ! queue ! dvdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! theoraenc ! queue ! mux.
```

If I remove the muxer and add filesink end points to the video and audio paths then it does not stall, but that creates two files I have to mux afterwards. I would rather do it in one pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a multiqueue after the demuxer. The multiqueue might be able to balance the amount of queued data better.